# Space interferes in sed replacement using shell variables

Tags: shell, sed

I am using sed in a shell script to replace a word in a file with a sentence that is stored in a shell variable. The sentence contains spaces and different characters.

Ex:

```
sentence="new number is > than 2.5 and < than 3.8"
sed "s|word|$sentence|g" -i Example_file.txt
```

Line in the file:

```
tile = "word - Final plot"
```

expected result:

```
title = "new number is > than 2.5 and < than 3.8 - Final plot"
```

obtained result:

```
title = "new - Final plot"
```

As you can see above, the problem is that `sed` always replaces "word" only with the first word of the sentence, it stops at the space. I tried different variations of the command:

```
sed 's|word|'"$sentence"'|g' -i Example_file.txt
sed "s|word|${sentence}|g" -i Example_file.txt
```

None of that seems to work. To check if the spaces were indeed the problem I replaced them with `"_"` , and when I do that, `sed` replaces using the whole sentence.

Anyone knows how can I force sed to take in the spaces and use the whole sentence?

Comment: This is very hard to read. Please use the "code formatting" button to format your code/command lines. It's a single click!

Comment: Thanks Inian for making the change!

Comment: Are you using `GNU` sed?. Works fine on `GNU sed version 4.2.1`

Comment: I am using GNU sed version 4.1.5. If I go to the shell and run the command interactively it does work. However it does not work if I run the script in a non-interactive way.

Comment: And you are saying, the same doesn't work from files?

Comment: I am saying I have a script in a *.sh file and does not work when I run this script. I only get the first word, never the sentence.

Comment: Can you try using `sed` expression script? it is working fine for me! `#!/bin/bash
sentence="new number is > than 2.5 and < than 3.8"
sed -e "s/\<word\>/$sentence/" abc.txt` for an input file `$cat abc.txt
tile = "word - Final plot"
tile = "word1 - Final plot"
`

Comment: @Inacio: you can add the in-place substitution flag along with it too! Can you see if the above is working?

Comment: @Inian: yep, it does work for me as well. However it does not work in my script, but I was not yet able to figure it out why. I am running script to run a second script, maybe is that the reason?

Comment: @Inacio: Please update the OP with the latest observations! it is not clear from the comments

Comment: @Inian: My example: file1 (with the sed script) - `#!/bin/sh sed -e "s/\<word\>/$1/" -i abc.txt` | file2 (running the sed script)   -  `#!/bin/sh sentence="new number is > than 2.5 and < than 3.8" ./File1.sh $sentence`

Comment: It's extremely unclear what you are trying to show us in that last comment. You show us `file1` containing a sed script which seems to have it's output piped to `file2` containing another shell script which is calling `File1.sh` which may or may not be what you mean by `file1` and contains an unquoted `$sentence` which may or may not be the problem. [edit] your question to show the shell script you are executing, the file you are executing it on, and the command line you are executing. Get rid of the `-i` option from the sed command first though so we can see the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, based on fixing what I THINK your comment under your question is telling us you are currently doing:

file1:

```
#!/bin/sh
sed 's/\<word\>/'"$1"'/' abc.txt
```

file2:

```
#!/bin/sh
sentence="new number is > than 2.5 and < than 3.8"
./file1 "$sentence"
```

Google "quote your shell variables". The above assumes you have GNU sed for word boundaries `\<...\>`. If you don't then get rid of them to see if it works then we can talk about how you address the need for them in other seds.

Comment: I was indeed not quoting the shell variable. The code also included some variable without space, and as it was working for those I assumed it would also work for the ones with space. Thanks a lot for your answer, it solved my problem.